# Wrong encoding of Word files uploaded to my server and processed by PHP script

Tags: php, utf-8, ms-word, character-encoding, cyrillic

I have a simple function (not mine one, actually) that opens and reads Word 97-2003 .doc files:

```
function docToText ($arrayOfFileProperties)
    {
        $pathToFile = $arrayOfFileProperties[1];
        $response   = '';
                 if(file_exists($pathToFile))
        {
            if(($fh = fopen($pathToFile, 'r')) !== false ) 
            {
               $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);

               $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );
               $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );
               $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );
               $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );
               $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);
               $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);
               return mb_convert_encoding($extracted_plaintext,'ISO-8859-5');                                          
            }
        }
```

`$pathToFile` is the property holding an uploaded .doc file. The file is being opened by `fopen` method, and then it gets `fread`-ed.

When people upload files containing Latin script, the resulting string is absolutely OK (UTF-8). But, I have users who can occasionally upload Russian .doc files, and in this case I get a string of gibberish, and different Russian decoding portals tell me it is UTF-8-encoded Cyrillic text. I do understand that it is because PHP does not know the encoding of the Russian files being uploaded, it just uses the UTF-8 encoding to just give me at least something. And, as you may see, I am trying to encode the output into ISO-8859-5 (why this particular encoding? see below).

The thing is that you can use https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/, e.g., to try to detect encoding of your Cyrillic text. It successfully converts my UTF-8-encoded Russian text into absolutely readable Russian ISO-8859-5, so, naturally, I tried to use this conversion info to try to de-code the output of my function, so that I can see the Cyrillic script properly. To no avail, actually.

Neither `mb_convert_encoding`, nor `iconv` are able to convert my gibberish to readable Russian text, even when I indicate 'ISO-8859-5' as the target encoding. Moreover, as far as I can see, it does not even matter what target encoding I put there for `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` methods - the text does not change at all. I still get UTF-8 gibberish of my Cyrillic text.

Is there any way to manipulate encodings in my case? The thing is that we have some 3 or 4 Cyrillic encodings, with one or two being almost always the case.

Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: Without using copy/paste on the source data, write something into your script that will output a hex or base64 encoded example string from your input that we can inspect.

Comment: This is what I get (just one exemplifying sentence): 0AB>OI89 0:>= 459AB2C5B =0 2A59 B5@@8B>@88  5A?C1;8:8 "0468:8AB0= 2 >B=>H5=88 2A5E D878G5A:8E 8 N@848G5A:8E ;8F. When using https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/, I can see the pair: 7-bit ASCII -> ISO-8859-5, and the corresponding Russian text.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the info.